# How to retrieve image width with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm creating a curation plugin for a custom solution.

When a Member gives an url, I retrieve all images, then I give the choice to choose an image from this page.

How could I only offer images which have a minimum width ? 
(Considering some img tags doesn't have width or height attributes)

Should  I parse each image ?
Or is there a solution with Jsoup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jsoup we can get only width and height attributes defined for the image tag  which displays the image on the page for the given pixels, but not exact width and height of the image, we can use ImageIO to get the exact width and height of the image as below:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://pictures.dealer.com/w/woodhouseomahaincfordfd/0027/a958ba95df26eaf392e298293da2847ex.jpg"));
            System.out.println(bimg.getWidth()+"==="+bimg.getHeight());
            bimg = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://pictures.dealer.com/ddc/resize/240x/quality/70/sharpen/1/ddc/w/woodhouseomahaincfordfd/0027/a958ba95df26eaf392e298293da2847ex.jpg"));
            System.out.println(bimg.getWidth()+"==="+bimg.getHeight());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want just attributes of an Image, we can use Jsoup api for this, the below code snippet depicts the same:

```
Elements images = document.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g|gif)]");
for (Element image : images) 
{
    System.out.println("height : " + image.attr("height"));
    System.out.println("width : " + image.attr("width"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to find a image's true size is to retrieve it.  Even if there is a width/height attribute in the HTML, it might not match the actual dimensions of the image.  JSoup has provisions to allow you to get the full URI of an image given the base URL of the page you are parsing.

Comment: So you mean I should get the image, and use a FileImageInputStream or something else to get my image real size ?

Answer (score 1):

yes,you can store image using ImageIO.read(new BufferedImage(new URL(YOUR URL))) ,extract its size,height,width and store it in a File .

Here comes the JSOUP with File Parse. you can use JSOUP this way!!!
Take a look at ,

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-file